# Вставка новой записи

Tags: c#

Есть следующий код:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:/BD.mdb");
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ThemeTest (Id_theme, NameTheme, NumberQuestion, Prim) VALUES"+
"(5 ," + textBox1.Text + "," + numericUpDown1.Value.ToString + "," + textBox2.Text + ")";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
sqlConnection1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
this.Close();

   на строке выдает ошибки:
```

"(5 ," + textBox1.Text + "," + numericUpDown1.Value.ToString + "," + textBox2.Text + ")";

Как правильно указать поля для вставки?

Comment: Попробуйте после VALUES пробел поставить или переход на новую строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте параметры.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT ThemeTest (Id_theme, NameTheme, NumberQuestion, Prim) VALUES (@Id_theme , @NameTheme, @NumberQuestion, @Prim)",sqlConnection1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_theme", 5);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameTheme","test");
...
```

Comment: спасибо, за ответ! С с# разбираюсь совсем недавно...